# Configure Undertow Servlet to handle root context

Tags: undertow

Is there a way to configure Undertow to handle the root context? For example: I've set called setContextPath("/") and I would like to access my app using, for example, `http://localhost:8080/`

If I access `http://localhost:8080//`, it works :(.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Use a context root like test,http://localhost:8080/test, add setContextPath("test").

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to setup the deployment?

Comment: Hi, I'm working at the same project. The code is in [this class](https://github.com/asouza/vraptor-undertow/blob/master/src/main/java/br/com/caelum/vraptor/undertown/builder/VRaptorServer.java#L52-L61), when the context is "/" the behaviour described by @Alberto happens.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `setContextPath("")`

as if you do `setContextPath("/")` you are mapping your application under `"/"` which is already under `"/"`
that is why it responds to `"//"` url

Comment: Hi, I tried the code you suggested and I got this exception:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: UT000009: Path must be specified`
I also took a look in class PathMatcher and I found this: https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/util/PathMatcher.java#L110

Comment: Hi, the problem was not in the setContextPath. As ctomc said, we can pass an empty string. But you use "/" in the addPrefixPath("/") method.